# Cannot scroll down list when wrapped inside RefreshIndicator

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

```
SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(24),
              child: Form(
                key: _formSearcOrdershKey,
                autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
                child: TextFormField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    border: UnderlineInputBorder(),
                    labelText: 'Enter Data',
                  ),
                  onChanged: (value) => getData(value),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            RefreshIndicator(
              onRefresh: () => controller.callApi(0),
              child: ListView.separated(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                itemCount: controller.workOrders.length,
                separatorBuilder: (context, position) {
                  return Divider();
                },
                itemBuilder: (context, position) {
                  return ListTile(
                    isThreeLine: true,
                    title: Text(
                      'title',
                      maxLines: 1,
                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                      softWrap: false,
                    ),
                    onTap: () => {print('tap')},
                    subtitle: Text(
                      'text',
                      maxLines: 1,
                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                      softWrap: false,
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

I'm stumped why it doesn't work. AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics is active but it still doesn't work. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try remove `SingleChildScrollView`.

then change your `RefreshIndicator` to this.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(24),
            child: Form(
              // key: _formSearcOrdershKey,
              autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
              child: TextFormField(
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  border: UnderlineInputBorder(),
                  labelText: 'Enter Data',
                ),
                onChanged: (value) {},
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: RefreshIndicator(
              onRefresh: () => callApi(),
              child: ListView.separated(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                itemCount: 10,
                separatorBuilder: (context, position) {
                  return Divider();
                },
                itemBuilder: (context, position) {
                  return ListTile(
                    isThreeLine: true,
                    title: Text(
                      'title',
                      maxLines: 1,
                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                      softWrap: false,
                    ),
                    onTap: () => {print('tap')},
                    subtitle: Text(
                      'text',
                      maxLines: 1,
                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                      softWrap: false,
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: it throws overflow error.

Comment: now it's working. try this code now. warp `RefreshIndicator` inside an `Expanded` widget.

Comment: this did it. Thanks a lot. Can you explain exact reason why this worked so i know for future

Comment: `ListView.separated` should be inside a widget like `Expanded` or `SingleChildScrollView` to handle the widget when it's bigger than screen.